# Differentiating breakpoints and search results in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

When searching for string occurrences (ctrl+F), in the vertical file scroll bar, I can't see the difference between a search result and a breakpoint. Here, the top 3 brown entries are search results, and the bottom 2 are breakpoints. As far as I'm aware my Visual Studio configuration is vanilla.

[image: brown squares on a vertical scrollbar]

Can this be addressed, perhaps via configuration ? How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Tools**/**Options**/**Environment**/**Fonts and colors**:**Text Editor** and customize the Display Item for:

- **Find Match Highlight** (affects both the in-editor hilite and scrollbar).
- **Breakpoint (Scroll Bar)**

To make an item not visible set the background to **Automatic**.